# My bootstrap form has two un-clickable inputs, can't figure out why

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap 3 form.

when its in the tabled and larger media query state, the middle input field is somehow overlaying the two inputs above making them none clickable `jsfiddle.net/wT7gp/`.

I have put an example in jsfiddle. (remember to make it wide enough to see the problem)

Repro:
Open link.
make the outwindow large.
click the input for firstname.

Expected it to start typing state, but nothing happens.

Hope someone here can explan what I did to cause it :) I failed at finding the issue. (other then yes the middle element is overlaying the two others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be wrapping your rows of form groups in `div` with `row` class like so:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wT7gp/1/
**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group  col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="First Name" id="first-name" tabindex="1" name="FirstName" data-bind="value: firstName" type="text" maxlength="50" />
        <label for="first-name" style="display:none;" data-bind="validationMessage: firstName, css: { error: !firstName.isValid() }" class="error"></label>
    </div>

    <div class=" form-group col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="Last Name" id="last-name" tabindex="2" name="LastName" data-bind="value: lastName" type="text" maxlength="50" />
        <label for="last-name" style="display:none;" data-bind="validationMessage: lastName, css: { error: !lastName.isValid() }" class="error"></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="Email" id="email" tabindex="3" name="Email" data-bind="value: email" type="email" maxlength="50" />
        <label for="email" style="display:none;" data-bind="validationMessage: email, css: { error: !email.isValid() }" class="error"></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="Choose a password" id="password1" tabindex="4" name="Password" data-bind="value: password" type="password" />
        <label for="@Html.CamelCaseName(Name)" style="display:none;" data-bind="validationMessage: password    , css: { error: !password.isValid() }" class="error"></label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="password, again" id="password2" tabindex="5" name="ConfirmPassword" data-bind="value: confirmPassword" type="password" />
        <label for="@Html.CamelCaseName(Name)" style="display:none;" data-bind="validationMessage: confirmPassword   , css: { error: !confirmPassword.isValid() }" class="error"></label>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @s093294 if I have answered your question, please check the little checkmark beside my answer and mark it as answer. If there is still an issue, please comment it or update your post :).

Comment: Huh ?!  Well, it fixed my issue aswell, but I've no idea why these class="row" div's made such a difference !

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It was caused by a div covering my input controls. It seemed the `div` 'knew no bounds'.

So when I worked out which div was causing the problem I applied the `overflow:hidden;` style.
I'm guessing that's why the `row` class worked for Kevin Pei - maybe it keeps the col divs contained.

*Aside:* I used Firefox Firebug to show me which div was covering my controls.

Comment: Same here @kartikg3, i just found the div and for me instead of applying overflow:hidden I just applied col-xs-12 so that my div re-sized correctly. The div ends up like this for me <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

Comment: OMG. Me too. What a waste of time, but I'm so glad @kartikg3 posted this answer. I think that my problem is the customised `form-group` in the 3rd-party template I'm using forces me to not use `form-group  col-xx-xx` the way it should be so the `rows` then 'know no bounds'...

Answer (score 3):

We had a very similar problem within our web application. Using `bootstrap 3.3.7` our signup form did not work any more on iPhones. The initial form looked like this:

```html
<form ...>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group string required">
            <input ...>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group string required">
            <input ...>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group string required">
            <input ...>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem was caused by the last two `div` elements which did not have corresponding class definitions for the `xs`-size. So on iPhone the `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">` class resulted in a very big `div` overlaying the whole form and preventing touch events for input fields beneath the `div`.

The solution is simply adding a `xs`-size class to the div and everything worked well on iPhones. In our case we adjusted the form like that:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group string required">
        <input ...>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i set z-index:1 for the controls not allowing inputs and no z-index setting for the controls allowing inputs.